# Create a Helper class from a Controller's method thats getting fat

Tags: asp.net-core

This method receive a CSV file (Sale, Date) POSTed from front-end, cleans a table and inserts csv file record into the table, then gets latest Date and returns it to the front-end. I know the code looks a bit ugly and I have a lot to learn but what I am trying to figure out here is how to create a Helper class from this code since the method is getting too fat I gess?

So I tried to migrate some of the code to a Helper class then I created a static Class but the problem is that I couldn't inject dependencies into its constructor since it was an static Class... then no database service from the Helper class and this is not too "helper".

So in your opinion, is this method too long/ fat?
Is there a need for a Helper Class?
How can I build it?

Cheers

Here my Controller

```
private IDataService<Sale> _SaleDataService;
    private readonly MyOptions _myOptions;
    public DateTime LastWindowDay;
    public ForecastApiController(IDataService<Sale> service, IOptions<MyOptions> optionsAccessor)

    {
        _SaleDataService = service;
        _myOptions = optionsAccessor.Value;         
    }

[HttpPost("api/Sales/uploadFile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles()
{
    try
    {
        //clean table
        var all = _SaleDataService.GetAll();
        if (all.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in all)
            {
                _SaleDataService.Delete(item);
            }
        }
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        //Read Request for the unique uploaded file (method can process multiple but frontend will post just one)      
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                //Reads the file one line at a time until its end
                String line = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    //Split the values on the line and convert them into a propper format
                    var fileLine = sr.ReadLine();
                    var lineToArray = fileLine.Split(',').ToArray();
                    var timeElement = DateTime.Parse(lineToArray[0]);
                    var saleAmauntElement = float.Parse(lineToArray[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    //Discard negative values and store data into database
                    if (saleAmauntElement >= 0)
                    {
                        //Store line into database
                        Sale sl = new Sale
                        {
                            SaleDate = timeElement,
                            SaleAmount = saleAmauntElement
                        };
                        _SaleDataService.Create(sl);
                        LastWindowDay = sl.SaleDate;
                    }
                }
                // Simple Moving Average method will be used and the restriction is that it will calculate only within a week after -
                // - last day of historical data.
                // Create an array and stores the next 7 days from the last day that there is data
                string[] predictionDays = new string[7];
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    predictionDays[i] = LastWindowDay.AddDays(i + 1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                }
                //returns the array to frontend to let the user select a prediction day
                return Json(predictionDays);
            }
        }
        return Json(new { message = "Error trying to process information" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new { message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the Repository pattern helps to maintain the controllers and the project in general, it is like having a helper class with all your operations (business logic and DB).

In your Startup.cs

```
 services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
```

Create an Interface

```
public interface IRepository
{

    IEnumerable<MyData> GetData();
}
```

Create your helper class

```
public partial class Repository : IRepository
{
    private DBContext _context;
    private ILogger<Repository> _logger;
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public Repository(DBContext context, ILogger<Repository> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    }
    public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return (await _context.SaveChangesAsync()) > 0;
    }
    public IEnumerable<MyData> GetData()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Getting All Data from the Database");
        return _context.Data.ToList();
    }
}
```

Finally inject it in your Controller

```
public class RequestsController : Controller
{
    private IRepository _repository;
    private ILogger<RequestsController> _logger;
    private IConfiguration _config;

    public RequestsController(IRepository repository,ILogger<RequestsController> logger,IConfiguration config)
    {

        _repository = repository;
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
    }

    // GET: Requests
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = _repository.GetData()
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean..to create a service and instead of injecting my data services into the controller I can do it into the service. And the i just inject my (Service Helper Class) into the controller? So there has to be an interface where to declare the methods.. it this ok?

Comment: Exactly! and that will keep a clear track of all the methods.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice approach is to follow the repository pattern as advised by [Steve Tolba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48859463/5959372). The repository pattern alleviates the bulk of query logic, transformation of view Models and the calling of business models from the controller.

However, if for whatever reason you do not want to follow the repository pattern and just want to split up your controller, you may pass the reference to the controller as a parameter to another action method:

```
    [HttpGet("myActionMethodThatUsedToBeFat")]
    public int MyActionMethodThatUsedToBeFat()
    {
        await HelperAction(this);
        //Do stuff...
    }

    private async Task<byte[]> HelperAction(Controller controller)
    {
        //Do stuff in here that would have made the calling action method too bulky
    }
```